# Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

Here is my query. I got that error. Please help me. Thanks.

```
ASC
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CostAllocation_Test]
@CompanyCode VARCHAR(3),
@EmpCode VARCHAR(600),
@PayCode VARCHAR(600)

AS
SELECT

CTPY33PAYRP.CTPAPECOD As EmployeeCode,
CTPY33PAYRP.CTPAPPCOD As paycode,
(select PY11RPTFPD.rpcol as columntotal from  PY11RPTFPD where rppcod =CTPAPPCOD) ,


(SELECT COCODE,CTPAPECOD,CTPAPPCOD
 FROM CTPY33PAYRP

WHERE CTPY33PAYRP.COCODE = @CompanyCode 
AND CTPY33PAYRP.CTPAPECOD =@EmpCode 
AND CTPY33PAYRP.COCODE = @CompanyCode
AND CTPY33PAYRP.CTPAPPCOD=@PayCode) As PayCode_Check,
PY11RPTFPD.RPPCOD As PayType,
(SELECT RPCOL,RPPCOD
        FROM  PY11RPTFPD,CTPY33PAYRP
        WHERE CTPY33PAYRP.CTPAPPCOD=PY11RPTFPD.RPPCOD)
from CTPY33PAYRP,PY11RPTFPD
ORDER BY CTPAPECOD
```

Answer (score 1):

I have to say your naming conventions aren't exactly transparent!

Without knowing the schemas for your tables it's a bit hard to say for sure, but I would guess that you are having trouble with this sub-query:

```
(SELECT COCODE,CTPAPECOD,CTPAPPCOD FROM CTPY33PAYRP
 WHERE CTPY33PAYRP.COCODE = @CompanyCode AND CTPY33PAYRP.CTPAPECOD =@EmpCode 
 AND CTPY33PAYRP.COCODE = @CompanyCodeAND CTPY33PAYRP.CTPAPPCOD=@PayCode) As PayCode_Check,
```

and with this sub-query:

```
(SELECT RPCOL,RPPCOD
    FROM  PY11RPTFPD,CTPY33PAYRP
    WHERE CTPY33PAYRP.CTPAPPCOD=PY11RPTFPD.RPPCOD)
```

You are selecting multiple columns from one table, in the first case, and from a join of two tables in the second case.  There is nothing in either sub-query which restricts the results to a single row.  If you are going to include a sub-query in your select list the sub-query has to return a single row per row in your main query.  Also, I've never seen a sub-query with multiple columns.

Since I have no clue from your table and column names what it is the query is meant to do, I can't give you much definitive advice about how to fix the syntax errors.  I would say **keep your sub-selects to one column each**.  This is what the error message is telling you.  Also you should either correlate the subqueries with the main query so that only one value is possible or use an aggregate function in the sub-queries to ensure that only a single value is possible for each record in the main query.

I will also say as an aside that you should learn ANSI join syntax.  It seems tricky at first, but it is your friend once you get used to it.